# How to get sum of date hours + min

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, date-arithmetic

```
     <tr data-ng-repeat="timesheet in timesheets">
                    <td>{{timesheet.startDate  | date:'dd/MM'}}</td>
                    <td>{{timesheet.startTime  | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
                    <td>{{timesheet.endTime  | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
                    <td>{{timesheet.breakTime  | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
                    <td>{{timesheet.totalTime | date:'HH:mm'}}</td>
                    <td >{{timesheet.note}}</td>

                </tr>
```

and i want to make a new variable with the sum of all timesheet.totalTime, timesheet.totalTime is a date, so i can use getHours and getMinutes

So my question is how i can make a new int/number var, that get the sum of totaltime
eg..

```
   <td>{{timesheet.totalTime | date:'HH:mm'}}</td> //= 09:30
   <td>{{timesheet.totalTime | date:'HH:mm'}}</td> //= 10.45
   <td>{{timesheet.totalTime | date:'HH:mm'}}</td> //= 01:15
   <td>{{timesheet.totalTime | date:'HH:mm'}}</td> //= 10.00
   <td>{{timesheet.totalTime | date:'HH:mm'}}</td> //= 10.00

<td>{{timesheet.totalTimeSum}}</td> //= 41.30  ??
```

how do i make this on controller side

Comment: Can you post the javascript that sets the timesheet property? When you want it to sum to 41.30, do you mean 41.5 hours, or 41 hours and 30 minutes?

Comment: its an query $scope.timesheets = Timesheets.query(); , and i want hours and min total of the, timesheet :)

Comment: What is the value of the date part? Would you ever have 24 or more hours in one of the timesheet.totalTime fields?

Comment: there is one timesheet for each day,  10x timesheet.totalTime = more then 24 hours

Comment: Look at using `Date.parse(timeSheet.totalTime)` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) to get the milliseconds for each date. Then, you can calculate the number of minutes, sum them up for all of your totalTimes, and print them nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller method that uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum `timesheets`:

```
$scope.timesheets = [
    {
        totalTime: 1
    },
    {
        totalTime: 3
    },
    {
        totalTime: 2
    },
    {
        totalTime: 10
    }    
];

$scope.totalTimeSum = function () {
    return $scope.timesheets.reduce(function (memo, timesheet) {
        // assuming you've DI'd $filter
        var time = $filter('date')(timesheet.totalTime, 'HH:mm');
        return memo + (+time);
    }, 0); 
}; // 16
```

Depending on which browsers you're supporting, you may need to shim `Array#reduce` or use lodash/underscore.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjoe64gw/)

Comment: I think the totalTime properties are date/times. I'm not very familiar with AngularJS, but I think the `{{timesheet.totalTimeSum}}` would need to change to `{{totalTimeSum}}`, for your example.

Comment: timesheets is an query from mongodb, and totalTime is an Date object and not a Number as in your example :s

Comment: I've added some code that _should_ parse `Date`s as required. It hasn't been tested, though, so YMMV.